how to change parameter enableTextToSpeech and outputAudioEncoding via API
I've used the API to automatically create a new chatbot, and I've figured out almost everything. However, there's one small issue that's preventing my bot from working. I need to change two settings:
Enable Text-to-Speech: This setting should be turned on.
Output Audio Encoding: This should be set to MP3 format.
Unfortunately, I can't find a way to do this using the Python API. Adding these parameters directly to the imported agent doesn't work either, as they seem to be ignored.
Additionally, I attempted to import the agent with the parameter
'textToSpeechSettings': { 'enableTextToSpeech': true, 'outputAudioEncoding': 'OUTPUT_AUDIO_ENCODING_MP3' }
, but this parameter was simply ignored.
I'm stuck and need help. Does anyone know how to fix this?
